# Tweepy - 'tweet.text' not retrieving text

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am brand new to Python, APIs, and coding in general.

I am working on a Twitter sentiment analyzing bot, but I cannot figure out why it isn't returning the `text` field. Everytime I run my script, PyCharm gives me `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`. Could anyone please help?

I have defined my tokens and API keys above these lines:

```
def authentication(cons_key, cons_secret, access_token, access_secret):
    auth = tw.OAuthHandler(cons_key, cons_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(acces_token, access_secret)
    api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

#Sentiment Analysis Block
query = input('Enter keyword/hashtag to search: ')
#numtweets = int(input('How many tweets you would like analyzed: ')) #update with paginator

#Defining percentage, for use on percent of sentiment
#def percentage(part, whole):
#    return 100 *float(part)/float(whole)

tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=100)
#positive = 0
#neutral = 0
#negative = 0
#polarity = 0
#tweet_list = []
#positive_list = []
#neutral_list = []
#negative_list = []

for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    #tweet_list.append(str(tweet.text))
    #analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    #score = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer().polarity_scores(tweet.text)
    #pos = score['pos']
    #neu = score['neu']
    #neg = score['neg']
    #comp = score['compound']
    #polarity += analysis.sentiment.polarity
```

As soon as the script gets to `print(tweet.text)`, it gives me the error. Any feedback?

Comment: You have defined the `authentication` function, but have not called it. Is this the whole code or is there more ?

Comment: This will be useful in helping you:    https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

`tweets` is a [`tweepy.Response`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/client.html#response) (named tuple) object. You're iterating over its fields rather than Tweet objects, and its first `data` field is a list of Tweet objects. Hence the error that the list doesn't have a `text` attribute. You probably want to iterate over the `data` field instead.

Comment: I have edited my script, and here is what I have now: